# Worth checking if an element exists first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

> **context:** I'm building a favouriting
>   system that uses html localstorage
>   API (with a php session fallback). If a favourited item is on the
>   page, add the class 'favourite' with js...

If I don't know whether the elements id will be present on the page. Is it better to check whether it exists first, or will jQuery return `false` just as efficiently?

Comment: How are you checking if "a favorited item is on the page" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is test code for a similar situation [on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-check-for-null-selector-or-just-perform-method2).

```
if ($('#item_123').length === 1) {
 $('#item_123').remove();
}
```

**VS**

```
 $('#item_123').remove(); //this turned out slower for me in chrome 13
```

Comment: Hm, turned out faster for me in Chrome 12. Also, [here's the revision with correct tags](http://jsperf.com/jquery-check-for-null-selector-or-just-perform-method2/4).

Comment: In your test, there's no matching element, so the `$('#item_123').remove();` in the first example *never runs*. As such, all you're doing is comparing `$('#item_123').length === 1` to `$('#item_123').remove();`. So yes, accessing the `.length` property will likely perform better than calling the `.remove()` method.

Comment: Thanks for sending me in the direction of jsperf

Answer (score 0):

Either way, you are always going to be executing `$()`. So keep a variable referencing the result of that method and there will be no loss (or highly negligible loss) in efficiency by checking if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's not. If jQuery finds no matches it will have nothing to enumerate and will just move on. In other words, something like this is unnecessary:

```
var $favorite = $("#favorite");
if ($favorite.length) {         // Test whether it exists
  $favorite.doSomething();
}
```

and is better written as:

```
$("#favorite").doSomething();
```